# Database design MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I want to design a database for Events.Events can be of two type normal event and event with session.Every events has some participant in it who have to give their feedback after the event is over if its normal event then they have to fill up a single feedback form but if event has session then each session gonna have a separate feedback form(here i am confused how to design it) and user have to fill that feedback form according to event session.

For example if a event has 3 session let name them A,B,C.Then a user will fill up the feedback form for session A after filling it,session B form will come up and he has to fill that form and then C but if user filled form A and logout and after he login again then the form he see thats gonna be Session B form.

Right now my database design look like below

Events Table

```
id event_name form_id date
```

here form_id is comming from feedback form table as there gonna be different types of form for each event,here if its normal event then i am passing that form_id in the table if its event session then i am keeping form_id 0

Events with session tables

```
id event_id form_id
```

Event_Users table

```
id user_id event_id is_submitted
```

here if normal event then i can make is_submitted 1 but what should i do for events thats gonna have session ? Shld i make another table for that ?

My Feedback form table where users feedbak gonna be store

```
id question_id user_id event_id session_id score
```

I know the question is a little bit confusing but pls read it again and if possible try to give me a solution

Comment: It would be better to treat all the events as session based events, have multiple sessions for events. If it is a single session event, have one entry in your session table, similarly, multiple session events will have multiple entries in sessions table. each session will receive feedbacks.

Comment: You can make every Event have at least one session. Then feedback goes to Session that is a child of Event instead of to the Event.

Answer (score 0):

The design methodology is to identify the entities -- the real-world things -- represented in your database. Then identify the relationships between them. Then identify the constraints.

## Entities:

- Event   one per event
- Session  one per session.  If the event has but one session, there's still an item here.
- Participant  one per participant person
- Evaluation  one per evaluation

## Relationships:

*I'm using the notation* One ==< Many *and* Many >==< Many *here.*

- Event ==< Session      One or more sessions per events.
- Event >==< Participant.  Many-to-many relationship between participants and events.
- (Session | Participant ) == Evaluation   Zero or one evaluations per participant in each session. (Zero? Yeah, good luck obtaining an evaluation from every participant.)

## Constraints

- Event ==< Session  Some, not all, events are constrained to have exactly one session.

## To make RDMS tables from this

You'll need a table for each entity and a join table for `event_person` , because of the many-to-many relationship.

```
event:         unique event_id                                 descriptive attributes.
session:       unique session_id  FK event_id                  descriptive attributes
person:        unique person_id                                descriptive attributes.
event_person:  FK person_id       FK event_id
eval           unique eval_id     FK session_id  FK person_id  descriptive attributes.
```

## Open question:

Is every participant in an event assumed to participate in every session of that event?  That is, should the Event >-< Person relationship actually be the Event >-< Session relationship?